# Streaking cumulative count with cancellation

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to create a count that accumulates streaks but can be cancelled by a different column. There are three outcomes in this count

- The streak accumulates based on flag == true.
- The streak resets on cancel on cancel == true.
- The streak does nothing and repeats the current streak.

I have tried several different approaches attempting to combinine the flag and cancel using np.where, masking groupby with where, multiple cumsums, fills, and ngroup, but cannot get the result wanted.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "cond1": [True, False, True, False, True, False, True],
        "cond2": [False, False, False, True, False, False, False]
    })

df['flag'] = np.where(df['cond1'], 1, 0)
df['cancel'] = np.where(df['cond2'], 1, 0)

# Combined
df['combined'] = df['flag'] - df['cancel']

# Cumsum only
df['cumsum'] = df['combined'].cumsum()

# Cumcount masked by where
df['cumsum_cumcount'] = df.where(df['cond1']).groupby((df['cond2']).cumsum()).cumcount()

# Cumcount then cumsum
df['cumsum_cumcount_cumsum'] = df.where(df['cancel'] == False).groupby(df['flag'].cumsum()).cumcount().cumsum()
```

```
    cond1   cond2   flag    cancel  c2  c3  c1
0   True    False    1         0    0   0   1
1   False   False    0         0    1   1   1
2   True    False    1         0    2   1   2
3   False   True     0         1    0   2   1
4   True    False    1         0    1   2   2
5   False   False    0         0    2   3   2
6   True    False    1         0    3   3   3
```

```
    cond1   cond2   streak
0   True    False     1
1   False   False     1
2   True    False     2
3   False   True      0 
4   True    False     1
5   False   False     1 
6   True    False     2     
7   True    False     3
8   False   False     3
9   True    False     4
10  False   True      0
11  False   False     0
12  True    False     1
```

The current streak repeats, accumulates when cond1 is true and resets when cond2 is false. Big bonus points if this could accumulate in the opposite direction too without too much hassle. Cancels being negatives flags being positives.

Comment: Thanks in advanced is not correct, it's thanks in advance (ie in advance, I'm thanking you).  Regardless pleasantries on stackoverflow have caused [much strife](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it), and do not contribute to QA.  Given that would you please remove the thanks at the end of your post? It will help save time for our curators who will end up removing it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need `cumsum` with `cond2` create the group key then `cumsum` with `cond1`

```
df.groupby(df.cond2.cumsum()).cond1.cumsum()
Out[155]: 
0     1.0
1     1.0
2     2.0
3     0.0
4     1.0
5     1.0
6     2.0
7     3.0
8     3.0
9     4.0
10    0.0
11    0.0
12    1.0
Name: cond1, dtype: float64
```